# Why I can't know if PostGIS is correctly installed on my PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, rdbms, postgresql-9.6

I am absolutly new in **PostgreSQL** and I am following this tutorial to check if I have **PostGIS** extension installed on my **PostgreSQL** installation.

This is the tutorial: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/determining-the-postgresql-and-postgis-versions

I am using **PostgreSQL 9.6.1**.

So I have access to my **PostgreSQL** via the command line and I performed this command:

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

This is the obtained output:

C:\Users\Andrea>pasql -u admin
'pasql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
C:\Users\Andrea>psql -U postgres
psql (9.6.1)
ATTENZIONE: Il code page della console (850) differisce dal code page
            di Windows (1252). I caratteri a 8-bit potrebbero non
            funzionare correttamente. Vedi le pagine di riferimento
            psql "Note per utenti Windows" per i dettagli.
Digita "help" per avere un aiuto.

postgres=# SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
ERROR:  function postgis_full_version() does not exist
RIGA 1: SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
               ^
NOTA: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
postgres=#
```

So I have done the access to the database with the standard user and then I have performed the command but seems that the **PostGIS_full_version()** function doesn't exist.

So what is means? It means that simply **PoistGIS** is not yet installed or am I doing something wrong? (maybe have I to perform it on a specific database?)

Comment: So how did you install it?

Comment: @zerkms I only installed  PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on my windows local machine

Comment: So, if you did not install postgis - it's not installed.

Comment: @zerkms I have this doubt because I have downloaded this "Graphical installer by BigSQL" from here: https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Comment: how can you see reading the description it say that "Integrated components include web and desktop developer tools, geospatial,..." so it seems that GEOSPATIAL functions are provided by default, what is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: If so - you need to enable it for the given schema first: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions

Comment: @zerkms ok...bus so why I obtain this error when I perform the "SELECT PostGIS_full_version();" statment? So, is it installed or not?

Comment: It is should be enabled for every database, see my previous comment.

Comment: @zerkms what do you mean when you say: "for the given schema"? You mean the irst preinstalled "postgres" schema? or what?

Comment: Sorry, I meant database. You need to enable it for every database.

Comment: Generally, create a new database named (e.g.) `postgis`, and then `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

Answer (score 6):

You have at least two problems. First of all,

```
Il code page della console (850) differisce dal code page
        di Windows (1252)
```

means that you have an older version of Postgres installed, so that, when you type psql from somewhere, this older version is found. I don't use Windows any more, but I am guessing the location will be set in the PATH of your environment variables. It is generally a bad idea to run incompatible version of the client and server. You can fix this by removing the path to the older (presumably 8.xx) version of Postgres.

The 2nd problem, is that you are running

> SELECT PostGIS_full_version();

from the Postgres DB, as you can see from the

> postgres=#

at the start. When you install Postgis, usually via

> CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS;

you would normally do this in the DB that you want to spatially enable and not in Postgres db, which is for system tables and the like. Note, Postgis is not installed globally. The other option is to install Postgis functions into the template1 db, which means all subsequent databases you create will automatically have Postgis installed.